# How to use css property attr here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have next realized tooltips (see snippet code).

```css
body
{
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;

    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button
{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    color: #fff;
    background-color: #21262b;

    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;

    font-weight: 700;
}

.button {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.button::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    background: #21262b;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
    min-width: 50px;

    left: 50%;
    top: -100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #21262b;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 50%);
}

.button::before,
.button::after {
    opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover::before,
.button:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum" class="button">Tooltip Button</button>
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum" class="button">Tooltip Button</button>
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum" class="button">Tooltip Button</button>
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum" class="button">Tooltip Button</button>
```

I want to add an additional data attribute for each button. Let me say it would be data-tooltip-left, data-tooltip-bottom, data-tooltip-top, data-tooltip-right. And for separate pseudo element after i want to change position. Or i just should remove general attribute data-tooltip? And for each of data-tooltip-*position* applying same styles but different position.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have multiple tooltips at the same time, right?(one above. one under, one left, and one right)and you want the value of these tooltip comes front an attribute in the button, correct?

Comment: exactly, youre right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

In your case, you can set position like this `data-tooltip-position="bottom"`.

The only one position attribute is enough, to prevent mistake for multiple position like this <s>`data-tooltip-bottom="" data-tooltip-top=""`</s>. They are opposite positions.
For more combine position you can use `data-tooltip-position="bottomleft"`.

Example:

```
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum" class="button">Tooltip Button</button>
<button data-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum bottom" class="button" data-tooltip-position="bottom">Tooltip Button</button>
```

In CSS, use selector like this.

```
.button[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: -100%;
}
.button[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]::before {
    top: 100%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 100%);
}
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/x75zvhru/)

Answer (score 0):

/*try using this way*/

```css
a:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

/*this link might help you as well*/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()